# multiple import and plot

Tags: plotting, import

I used the following code to import all the file from one folder and perform operation on it. But I can't get my graphic...Should I need to use Table somewhere to plot them but I don't see where...

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"];

file = FileNames["*.dat", NotebookDirectory[]];

func[{file_String /; FileExistsQ[file]}] := 
  Module[{data, dataT, formatted}, 
   data = Import[file, "Table"] & /@ file;
   dataT = Transpose[data];
   dataT = {dataT[[1]], dataT[[2]], dataT[[3]], dataT[[4]]};
   data = Transpose[dataT];
   formatted = {{#1, #2}, ErrorBar[#4, #3]} & @@@ data;
   ErrorListPlot[{formatted}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     Placed[LineLegend[{FileBaseName[file]}], {Right, Bottom}]]];

func /@ file
```

Comment: The issue is most likely the `;` after the `ErrorListPlot[…]`: It suppresses any output, also the plot, so just remove it. See [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompoundExpression.html) for more information

Comment: I removed it, but the problem is not fixed. Still can't see my Plot.

Comment: Did you ever test the code outside of a module to see if the single case works? One other issue i noticed: `data = Import[file, "Table"] & /@ file` should be just `data = Import[file, "Table"]`. Also, the next three lines are not needed I think (the just throw away some columns in a complicated way, but the `formatted = …` line doesn't care if there are too many)

Comment: Yes for one single case using data = Import[file, "Table"]. it works perfectly so then I wanted to extend it for all the files in in my folder using FileNames and &/@file

Comment: An what happens if you adjust the line inside the function as I've suggested? Currently, you're `Map`ping twice of the `file` list, once in a wrong way

Comment: Using just `data = Import[file, "Table"]` and removing the next three line don't change anything

Comment: Next time, please post any output you do get in the question - I was under the impression that there was none. There is another mistake in the signature of `func`: You define `func[{file}]` under certain conditions. If you look at your output, what you actually need to define is `func[file]` (notice the lack of curly braces)

Comment: It works. thanks and thanks for the advise. Mathematica is really new for me I started this week to use it...

Comment: If I want to plot each curve in different color how can I do that using PlotStyle ?

Comment: Just return the data from the function instead of the function and plot them using a single `ErrorListPlot`. Side note: Please do not post follow up questions in the same question/comments. Each question should be restricted to a single problem. (So look whether you find a solution to your problem and if not, post a new question)